# Convert number to string (number in string or null in string)

Tags: sql-server-2005

In SQL Server, what is the shortest way to convert a number to string (number in string or null in string):
Example:

number 1 ---> output '1'

number null --> output 'null'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee2e5/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table T
(
    Number int
);

insert into T values(1);
insert into T values(null);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select cast(Number as varchar(11))
from T;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee2e5/1/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
|----------|
|        1 |
|   (null) |
```

Or `isnull(cast(Number as varchar(11)), 'null')` if you are looking for the string value `null`.

Not sure what you man by shortest and why that is important but this is a bit shorter `isnull(left(Number, 11), 'null')`.